# Android - Convert/Display A Proper Value

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android application recently and I found out that the display of the output are quite weird especially when it comes to number.

For example, after going through a formulation.

The value shown on the TextView is **1.5460385687E-11**

My question is, how can I display the current above output in a proper way such as
**1.546E-11 or 1.546x10^11** ?

As requested, my code for displaying to the output.

```
double result = tPower * tGain * rGain * Math.pow(lamda / (4 * Math.PI *distance),2)/ light / 100;
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpacePrw)).setText(Double.toString(result));
```

Comment: could you post some of the code you are using?

Comment: I have edited my post with the code above

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DecimalFormat to format the result of your calculation before adding it to the TextView. The DecimalFormat class is configured using a pattern given in the constructor, such as "0.###E+0"

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html